# Font folder not linked properly

Tags: css, fonts, hyperlink, directory

Here is my structure within the root folder: `css/fonts/` and `books/book1.html`

Within the css folder I have a stylesheet which has a link to the fonts folder like: `src: url('/font/fontName.ttf');`

In the books folder, I link the stylesheet through: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">`

I have a:
`body { color: red }` in the stylesheet and all the color was effected as intended. However, for some reason the fonts were not loaded. When I moved the book1.html outside the books folder, and changed the stylesheet link to :  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">`

Can someone please help ?

[image]

Comment: You haven't completed your question.

Comment: @StephaneRolland `css/fonts` and `books/book1` are actually different directories. have a look at the OP's original markdown

Comment: Can you make a screendump of your directories and/or post a demo see we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @AnishGupta re-edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you change the following:

```
url('/font/fontName.ttf');
```

To:

```
url('/css/fonts/fontName.ttf');
```

It will work no matter where your css file is in the directory structure.

Comment: Is the folder called "font" or "fonts"? You interchange between the two in your question

Comment: font, I should have said font instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully understand your file/folder structure from your image, but does this work in your css?

```
src: url('./font/fontName.ttf');
```

(I added a dot before your forward slash)